# Azure Functions is not adding more servers to process the queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working on queue trigger based Azure function which is under consumption plan. Currently I have millions of messages in my queue which should be processed. Based on Azure Functions [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-plan-works) it should add more servers to be able to process my messages. However it's running only 145 servers and more than 2 millions messages are stuck on the queue for last 24 hours. Why Azure is not adding more servers to speed up the message processing? Is there any limit for the servers can be allocated for each Function App?

Comment: "Only 145" sounds nice. So was it scaling properly up to 145 and then fell flat?

Comment: Yes, it's scaling up to ~170 (this is the largest number I have seen during few days) but not more. But since messages are adding more frequently then processing my queue is just blowing up. My assumption is that Azure should add as many servers as need to process the queue. More servers, more executions therefore more will be charged but I don't know why it's scaling to some point but not more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795305/poor-throughput-on-azure-functions this might help

Comment: Please have a check whether it reaches the limit of azure subscription:[Subscription usage and quotas in the Azure portal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/skeeler/2017/01/subscription-usage-and-quotas-in-the-azure-portal/). If it is that case then we need to connect to Azure support for further help.

Comment: You are probably hitting the upper limit of what they allow you to scale to. I would reach out to the Azure Function team to get their help. Just open an issue in github, or ping them on twitter, they are very responsive.